# Bind parameter doesn't work with like in Firebird 2.0. Is there a workaround?

Tags: firebird

If I use a bind parameter with `like` it restricts the length of the parameter.

for example:

```sql
select * from rdb$database where :x like '%N';
```

If the `x` parameter is longer than 2 I get a string truncation exception. I'm using Firebird 2.0. Is there a way around it or bind parameters won't work with `like`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Firebird bind parameters are restricted to the same type and length as the field, column or value they are compared to. In this case you are comparing to a literal of two characters and it is considered a `CHAR(2)` by Firebird, so the bind parameter is also a `CHAR(2)`. This doesn't just apply to `like`, but to all comparison operations.

This means you cannot use a value longer than two characters for the parameter. There are two workarounds I know of:

- Cast the value, eg: `WHERE ? LIKE CAST('%N' AS VARCHAR(256))`
- Cast the parameter, eg: `WHERE CAST(? AS VARCHAR(256)) LIKE '%N'`